# Why are region headings blurry?

Tags: visual-studio, formatting, visual-studio-mac, code-regions

I recently migrated from visual studio code to visual studio (because vsc and unity wouldn't be friends), and my only gripe is minor, yet a major annoyance: Despite all other text looking fine and crisp, collapsed region headers are so blurry they border on unreadable on my small screen (See image).

[image]

I can't find any applicable settings or previous threads. I'm working from a mac, have yet to add any extensions, and use only default settings (except for dark mode ofc). Any ideas for causes or solutions would be greatly appreciated :)

Edit:
Am I just looking in the wrong place for my settings? Is Apple hiding stuff from me again?: [image][image]

Comment: Just guessing but I'd check font and color settings at *Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Display Items : Collapsible Region*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just edited the question. Any idea where I can find those color settings?